# GEE time-lapse comes out black and white

Tags: google-earth-engine, merge, landsat

I was trying to make a code that would create a time-lapse of the Aletsch glacier. Now this was just for fun and to improve my gee skills as I recently started working with it.

The problem that I have is the fact that the code runs but the images that come out are black and white. So I don't really get a time-lapse from this.

I have the following code that I am working with. Does someone know what the reason for this is?

```
// Define the location of the glacier
var geometry = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[7.998888041907808, 46.533796311532946],
          [7.998888041907808, 46.393323664501075],
          [8.104631450110933, 46.393323664501075],
          [8.104631450110933, 46.533796311532946]]], null, false);
          

// Function used to merge Landsat satelites 4,5,7,8
function mergeLandsat(satlist, imgcloud, yearrange, monthrange, dayrange, boundgeom, imageQ, pixcloud){
   
  if (satlist===undefined){satlist=[4,5,7,8]}
  if (imgcloud===undefined){imgcloud=100}
  if (yearrange===undefined){yearrange=[1984,2020]}
  if (monthrange===undefined){monthrange=[1,12]}
  if (dayrange===undefined){dayrange=[1,31]}
  if (boundgeom===undefined){boundgeom = geometry}
  if (imageQ===undefined){imageQ=-1}
  if (pixcloud===undefined){pixcloud='mild'}
  
  // get all landsat collections,
  var ls4rfl = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT04/C02/T1_L2");
  var ls5rfl = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2");
  var ls7rfl = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2");
  var ls8rfl = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2");
  
  // create filters for the whole collection (based on image metatdata)
  var ccFilt = ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER',imgcloud);
  var iQFilt = ee.Filter.gte('IMAGE_QUALITY',imageQ);
  var oliFilt = ee.Filter.gte('IMAGE_QUALITY_OLI',imageQ);
  var yearFilt = ee.Filter.date(yearrange[0]+'-01-01',yearrange[1]+'-12-31');
  var mFilt= ee.Filter.calendarRange(monthrange[0],monthrange[1], 'month');
  var dFilt = ee.Filter.calendarRange(dayrange[0],dayrange[1],'day_of_month');
  var recFilt = ee.Filter.bounds(boundgeom);
  //merge all the filters for landsat 457, 8
  var lsFilt = [ccFilt,iQFilt,yearFilt,mFilt,dFilt,recFilt];
  var ls89Filt = [ccFilt,oliFilt,yearFilt,mFilt,dFilt,recFilt];

  //function for renaming ls4-ls7 bands
  function l457Bands(x) {
      return x.select(['SR_B1','SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B7','QA_PIXEL'])
              .rename(['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','swir2','qa']);
  }
  
  //function for renaming l8 bands
  function l89Bands(x){
      return x.select(['SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B6','SR_B7','QA_PIXEL'])
              .rename(['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','swir2','qa']);
  }
  

  //function to get landsat quality flags for cloud masking
function lsCloudPx(image) {
  var qa = image.select('qa');
  var maskmildest = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3);    // pixels flagged as cloud
                  
  var maskmild = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 6).not() // pixels that are not clear (remove cloud and dialated cloud)
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4));  // high confidence cloud shadow
                  
  var maskstrict = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 6).not()// cloud or dialated cloud (high confidence onl)
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 8))  // medium and highconfidence cloud
                  //.or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 9))// low confidence cloud 
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 4))  // high confidence cloud shadow  (to include low use 11)
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 2))  // high confidence cirrus   (to include low use 15)
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)); // high snow and ice (to include low use 13)
                  //.or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7));// water
  
  var pixmask = (pixcloud==='mildest' ? maskmildest :
                 pixcloud==='mild' ? maskmild :
                 pixcloud==='strict' ? maskstrict : ee.Image(0) );                
                 
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(pixmask.not()).updateMask(mask2);
}  

  // filter the ls4,5,7 TM collection, select bands and rename them
  var ls4 = ls4rfl.filter(lsFilt).map(l457Bands).map(lsCloudPx);
  var ls5 = ls5rfl.filter(lsFilt).map(l457Bands).map(lsCloudPx);
  var ls7 = ls7rfl.filter(lsFilt).map(l457Bands).map(lsCloudPx);
  // filter the OLI collection, select bands and rename them
  var ls8 = ls8rfl.filter(ls89Filt).map(l89Bands).map(lsCloudPx);
  
  // create empty collection with a dummy image
  var out = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Image().select());       
  
  // merge collections based on 'satlist' argument
  if (satlist.indexOf(4) > -1){out = out.merge(ls4)}
  if (satlist.indexOf(5) > -1){out = out.merge(ls5)}
  if (satlist.indexOf(7) > -1){out = out.merge(ls7)}
  if (satlist.indexOf(8) > -1){out = out.merge(ls8)}

  // remove empty dummy image by filtering on band name
  out = out.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('system:band_names', 'nir'));
  return out;
}

// Create Image collection from the merged Landsat collection
var landsatAll = mergeLandsat() 

// Define the time range and interval
var startYear = 1984;
var endYear = 2020;
var startMonth = 1;
var endMonth = 12;
var interval = 1;

// Define the visualization parameters
var visParams = {
bands: ['swir2', 'nir', 'red'],
min: 0,
max: 3000,
};

// Create a time lapse animation
var timelapse = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear, interval)
    .map(function(year) {
      var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, startMonth, 1);
      var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, endMonth, 1);
      var image = landsatAll.filterDate(startDate, endDate).mosaic();
      return image.visualize(visParams).set('year', year);
    })
);

// Define the export parameters
var exportArgs = {
  collection: timelapse,
  description: 'aletsch_glacier_timelapse',
  dimensions: 1080,
  framesPerSecond: 1,
  region: geometry
};

// Export the timelapse animation to Google Drive
Export.video.toDrive(exportArgs);
```